# Open an other ViewController by touching a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch

I have a ViewController with full of names, basically a contact list. When you touch one of the names, you will get a detail screen with informations: name, organization, building, phone number, email, etc. It uses a navigation controller, so you can go back to the phonebook.

I have a custom map in my application (basically a picture, with several layers and with a pin, that show you where you are on the picture). I would like to achieve that when someone touch the building UILabel it goes my MapViewController with some parameters. It's a simple UILabel, but contains useful information, something like 15/A building. I have the exact x,y coordinates for the buildings.

My main problem is that I don't really know how to set up the touch event on the UILabel and go to a new view controller, with parameters.

I guess I need to make in my mapviewcontroller new initiation methods to be able to get parameters and display them.

So to summarize: how can I navigate to an other view controller with touch event and how can I initiate that view controller with parameters. It's important that I can reach my map without any buildings parameters as well from my menu.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: in the UILable place use button

Comment: i think Anbu is right...you may also use tap gesture(may be work on uilabel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Create a Tap Gesture and set it on your Label. 

UILabel *yourLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[yourLabel setText:@"Address"];
[self.view addSubview:yourLabel];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TapGestureRecognizerLabel:)];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];

 -(void)TapGestureRecognizerLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetControllerObj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, and it opens my other ViewController, but when it does I can only see a grey background. I assume this is app specific, but any particular idea about that? I'm trying without any parameters for now, but instead of my map picture I got only a grey background. If I open the map from my menu it's OK.

Comment: OK, I figured it out, instead of using [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetControllerObj animated:YES]; I made a new segue and use this [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromContactToMap" sender:self];. It makes me be able to make preparations with - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender; method. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Why not just make it a UIButton without a border or background. That way you don't need to bother with the tap gesture?

Comment: @Nick,you are right.you may also use UIButton on the place of UILabel.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can also add a hidden button over your label. This button will handle the touch event.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tap gesture for it

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped)];

tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;